# Как передать параметр при использовании join и where в eloquent

Tags: php, sql, eloquent

При вызове метода передаётся параметр с id покупателя (customer_id). Подскажите, как передать этот параметр в условие where. Если делать, как в коде ниже, то $customerId в условии подсвечен как undefined:

```
public static function getOrdersByCustomerId($customerId){
    $info = DB::table('crm_orders')
                ->join('crm_customers', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('crm_orders.customer_id', '=', 'crm_customers.customer_id')
                        ->where('crm_customers.customer_id', '=', $customerId);
                })
               ->get();
}
```

Comment: function($join)  use ($customer_id) (http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, Daniel Protopopov

```
public static function getOrdersByCustomerId($customerId) {
        $info = DB::table('crm_orders')
                    ->join('crm_customers', function ($join) use ($customer_id)  {
                        $join->on('crm_orders.customer_id', '=', 'crm_customers.customer_id')
                            ->where('crm_customers.customer_id', '=', $customerId);
                    })
                   ->get();
    }
```